# How to convert s-expression which is in string into a tuple in Python

Tags: python, command-line, tuples, s-expression

I have an S-expression in Python which I need to convert it into tuple with operators (add,multiply) inside the semi-colon ie as a string.

I have the following code snippet:

This code works fine, but the requirement of the work is that the user doesnot input tuple like `('add', ('multiply', 3, 4), 5)` instead pass an s-expression like `"(add (multiply 2 3) 2)"` from the system command line.

The command to put an input will be like this:

```
python calc.py "(add (multiply 2 3) 2)"
```

For now I have already defined expression in the code, but the users will be giving the expression and we fetch it using `sys.argv` . So how to convert the user input `"(add (multiply 2 3) 2)"` to `('add', ('multiply', 3, 4), 5)` so that I can use the above code easily.

**Update:**

I tried the following code but it didnt give the desired result.

```
def from_expression_string(expression_string):

    tokens = expression_string.strip().split()
    #['(add', '(multiply', '2', '3)', '2)']
    stack = []
    for token in tokens:
        if token == '(':
            # print("hello")
            pass
        elif token == ')':
            args = [stack.pop(), stack.pop()]
            stack.append((stack.pop(), *reversed(args)))
        else:
            try:
                stack.append(int(token))
            except ValueError:
                stack.append(token)
    return stack[0]
```

The output of this snippet gives `(add`. The above code seems easy to understand but is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can tokenize the input s-expression with a regex of an alternation pattern, iterate through the tokens while appending each token to a stack, but if the token is a left parenthesis, push the current size of the stack to another stack recording the stack positions of left parentheses, and if the token is a right parenthesis, pop the left parentheses stack for the nearest position of a left parenthesis and replace the items from the position with a new sub-list of these items. As long as the s-expression is well-formed, the stack should be left with a single item of the desired list output when all tokens are processed:

```
import re

def convert(s):
    stack = []
    lefts = []
    for token in re.findall(r'\w+|[()]', s):
        if token == ')':
            index = lefts.pop()
            stack[index:] = stack[index:],
        elif token == '(':
            lefts.append(len(stack))
        else:
            if token.isdigit():
                token = int(token)
            stack.append(token)
    return stack[0]

print(convert('(add (multiply 2 3) 2)'))
```

This outputs:

```
['add', ['multiply', 2, 3], 2]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ProfitableColorfulProlog

Comment: @blhsing I have added my code, but didnt give the correct output. If you can modify my update, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Reactoo Why you are using `str.split` instead of `re.findall`? With `str.split` you can't separate parentheses from the words.

Comment: can you write findall expression without using regex, i dont really understand regex.